# Understanding relationships in Parse.com application suite for IOS

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I am using Parse for the first time and am using the Data Browser. I have 2 tables: users and friends.  Each user in my app can have 50 friends.

So my db in Parse looks like:

```
Table Users:
username (unique)
email (unique)
friends (a one to many relationship to the friends table)

Table Friends:
email
name
whoseFriend (this is many to one to one friends in the Users table)
```

In the data browser, I set the the users friends as an array (per Parse's docs), but what do I set the whoseFriend as? Just a string? How do I go from the whoseFriend to find out what the parent friend is?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
 //Make it as array of dictionary. Suppose below is list of my friends "friendof" here we will show friend of friends 
{  
friendsList =     {  
    friendare =         (  
                    {    
            friendName =                 {  
                text = a;    
            };  
            friendof =                 {  
                friendnames =                     (  
                                            {  
                        text = 456;    
                    },  
                                            {  
                        text = 456;  
                    }  
                );  
            };  
        },  
                    {
            friendName =                 {  
                text = a;  
            };  
            friendof =                 {  
                friendnames =                     {  
                    text = 456;  
                };  
            };  
        }  
    );  
};  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> In the data browser, I set the the users friends as an array (per Parse's docs), but what do I set the whoseFriend as? Just a string? How do I go from the whoseFriend to find out what the parent friend is?

Parser doc say:

> Arrays are ideal when we **know that the number of objects** involved in our one-to-many relationship are going to be small

Maybe you using Pointer.
In your case:

1. Create Friend object

   ```
   PFObject *friend= [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Friends"];
   ```
2. Set whoseFriend

   ```
   [friend setObject:[PFUser currentUser] forKey:@"whoseFriend"];
   ```

   [PFUser currentUser] or other user
3. Find out what the parent friend

   ```
   PFQuery *friendQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Friends"];
   [gameQuery whereKey:@"whoseFriend" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
   ```